# python - select() on boolean variable

Tags: python, select, boolean, pygame, midi

i need to use `select()` on a bool because the module pygame.midi lets you know when a midi message is ready only through the function `Input.poll()` that returns a bool.

if i check this value in the simple way, i do busy waiting and my cpu works at 100% all the time.

is there a way to use the `select()` or similar functions to wait for a variable to change its value in a context without automatic event raising?

(i don't strictly need to live eventless, indeed i would love to use them, but i can't see midi events anywhere in the package..)

Comment: You mean [`select.select`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/select.html#select.select)? If so, you can't do that; it only takes file handles. Also, how would it help? It's just going to return immediately, or block forever, so you'd still have the same problem you're starting with.

Comment: Also, who's going to change the variable's value? Whatever code does that, you can just have it call your function instead.

Comment: @abarnert pygame.midi isnt code he is going to want to change

Comment: @cmd: But `pygame.midi` doesn't change a variable's value. So it's got to be his code calling its `read` or `poll` function that changes the value, and that code can just as easily call his function directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When developing games you usually do everything in a main loop. If you want e.g. 50 fps, then you want to go through this loop 50x per second. If you assume that you are not doing anything time consuming, then you can sleep for 20ms at the end of every iteration.

So I think that's the reason why only poll is available, you are supposed to check whether the midi is loaded in your loop. If it is, then you can do something with it, otherwise you would continue rendering or doing something else. Generally while creating games and apps that should have consistent fps, you don't want to wait for some event.

Comment: thanks i solved by waiting some milliseconds each cycle, i'm not developing a game, but a midi "translator" that changes the behavior of a midi device and sends midi to software sinthetizers, so i do not have the limit of the fps and i wanted somthing that could "wake up" my program when someone touched the midi device, but waiting for 10ms is largely sufficient to have the pc run extremely fine and the translator react quickly

Answer (score 0):

If your input doesn't have any way to fire events, you have to check it on a timer.

In most games, your main event loop already has some "frame limiter" code, so the event loop runs no more than 50 times/sec. So, you can just `poll` once per event loop. If not, you'll essentially have to add a frame limiter now.

If your game for some reason doesn't fit this paradigm—or if you need to poll the input much more often than your max frame rate—you have to write a background thread that reads from the input (blocking if possible, polling and sleeping if not) and either handles the events directly, or pushes then onto a queue that the main thread can read from each time through the loop.